# Absolute position auto width until max width

Tags: css, absolute

I want an absolute element to shrink/grow with its content until it reaches a max width, then wrap to multiple lines. The fiddle also contains what I'm looking to achieve.

http://jsfiddle.net/mqv9r7a6/

html

```
<div class = "cont">
  hello
  <div class = "inside">
    long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "cont">
  hello
  <div class = "inside">
    short
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.cont {
  background:red;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:50px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}

.inside {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
    background:orange;
    border:1px solid black;
    max-width:150%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: use media queries for it

Comment: What do media queries have to do with this? This is based strictly on the content of the elements.

Comment: The problem is that your parent container for the absolute positioned element is only that wide, so it can never exceed the width of the parent unless you explicitly increase the width to exceed 100%. It's just like how the content would wrap to the next line on a normal webpage with default styling. You can only achieve what you want with JS unless you change your structure. In the latter, the width has to be set 'auto' if you want it to change dynamically as long as below 100%, so you can combine both columns into one and set max-width, say, 60%.